# Documenter.jl: add parameters in @index block

Tags: julia, markdown, documentation-generation

When creating a documentation using `documenter.jl`, is it possible to add the parameters of a function when displayed from a

````
```@index
```
````

block? I.e. say I have a `function f(x)`, I want `f(x)` to be displayed in the `.html` instead of simply `f`, as I am currently getting.

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks like it's pretty much impossible without a lot of tweaking of `Documenter`. If you look at how an `@index` block is rendered to markdown, it stores references to documented functions in `Base.Docs.Binding`, which only has fields for module and name.

Comment: Ok too bad... thanks for letting me know.